# Paypal SDK Client ID

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm confused about the Client ID I have to enter here. I found a few similar answers, but they are all old and don't answer my question.

So I have to enter my Client ID's here:

```
PayPalMobile.initializeWithClientIds(forEnvironments: [PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "HERE", PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "HERE"])
```

But I don't know if I have to create REST API credentials or v.zero SDK credentials

I tried REST API first, but it didn't work.

And do I only need client ID's? So I don't have to enter the secrets to the email addresses anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to go to paypal developer account then

1- Go to Dashboard.
2- Create app.
3- you will find two tabs(sandbox and    production) each one will give you an id to test on either modes.

you should also create testing accounts to make testing payments in sandbox mode

[Here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) is a good documentation for Paypal mobile.